# I cannot go pass the Database creation stage in configuring report server for Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Please I am trying to configure my Report Server for Power BI Service but I cant go pass the creation of database. I keep getting error. Screenshot of the error is attached below. Please I need help to figure this out, Thank you,
[image]

Comment: What version of SQL Server  you trying to host it on?

Comment: SQLserver 2018 is what I am using

Comment: What edition? Standard, Enterprise, Developer?

Comment: SQLSERVER 2019 Enterprise, Sorry for replying late

Comment: This question and answer may help https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223418/error-while-trying-to-create-a-database-for-ssrs